# Having trouble getting SSL working in Node.js App

Tags: node.js, ssl

EDITED

I am trying to get SSL working on an app, but I just can't get it to work.  I am having problems troubleshooting the problem.

I have created a basic app to test it:

```js
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/server_key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/server_crt.pem'),
  passphrase: 'mypassphrase',
  ca: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/cacert.pem'),
  requestCert: true,
  rejectUnauthorized: false
};

https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
  console.log('req.client.authorized: %s', req.client.authorized);
  if (req.client.authorized) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end("hello world\n");
  }
  else {
    res.writeHead(404);
    res.end("Not authorised\n");
  }

}).listen(3000);
console.log('Server started...');
```

I have created the certificates using [Ubuntu Documentation on OpenSSL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenSSL). The process I used was:

1. Create Certificate Authority Root Certificate and Key

   > export OPENSSL_CONF=~/myCA/caconfig.cnf
   >
   > openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -out cacert.pem -outform PEM -days 1825

   which generates: the CA public certificate 'cacert.pem'; and CA private key 'cakey.pem'
2. Create Self-Signed Server Certificate

   > export OPENSSL_CONF=~/myCA/exampleserver.cnf
   >
   > openssl req -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout tempkey.pem -keyform PEM -out tempreq.pem -outform PEM
   >
   > mv tempkey.pem server_key.pem
   >
   > export OPENSSL_CONF=~/myCA/caconfig.cnf
   >
   > openssl ca -in tempreq.pem -out server_crt.pem

   which generates: Server application certificate file 'server_crt.pem'; and Server application key file 'server_key.pem'.
3. Create PKCS#12 certificate from server's Root CA X.509 certificate for client use

   > openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout mycert.pem -out mycert.pem
   >
   > openssl pkcs12 -export -out mycert.pfx -in mycert.pem -name "Certificate for MySite"

   Which results in the file 'mycert.pfx'.
4. Copy files to app's ssl directory

   I copy the files 'cacert.pem', 'server_key.pem', and 'server_crt.pem' to the ssl directory of the app.
5. Import file 'mycert.pfx' into Firefox via Firefox's built-in Certificate Manager (I import it into the tab marked 'Your Certificates').
6. Enter URL (`https://ssl:3000`) into Firefox

   At this point I receive an 'User Identification Request' from Firefox, from which I select my certificate. Then I receive an error from Firefox saying:

   "... Secure Connection Failed
    An error occurred during a connection to ssl:3000.
    Peer's certificate has an invalid signature.
    (Error code: sec_error_bad_signature) ..."

I tried trouble shooting with `curl -v -s -k -E mycert.pem:somepassword https://ssl:3000`, and receive the following output:

> - About to connect() to ssl port 3000 (#0)
> - Trying XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX... connected
> - successfully set certificate verify locations:
> - CAfile: none
>     CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
> - SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
> - SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
> - SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
> - SSLv3, TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
> - SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
> - SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
> - SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
> - SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
> - SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
> - SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
> - SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
> - SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
> - SSL connection using AES256-SHA
> - Server certificate:
> - subject: CN=ssl; ST=Beijing; C=CN; emailAddress=root@localhost; O=Bengul Company; OU=Bedroom
> - start date: 2012-07-17 05:11:49 GMT
> - expire date: 2017-07-16 05:11:49 GMT
> - subjectAltName: ssl matched
> - issuer: CN=ssl; ST=Beijing; C=CN; emailAddress=root@localhost; O=Bengul Company; OU=Bedroom
> - SSL certificate verify result: self signed certificate (18), continuing anyway.
>     GET / HTTP/1.1
>     User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
>     Host: ssl:3000
>     Accept: */*
>
> HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
>
> Date: Tue, 17 Jul 2012 05:22:04 GMT
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>
> Not authorised
>
> - Connection #0 to host ssl left intact
> - Closing connection #0
> - SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):

If I then run `netstat` I get this output:

> Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
>
> Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
>
> tcp        0      0 ssl:55719               ssl:3000                TIME_WAIT

I can't work out what I am doing wrong.  I would be extremely grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently implemented a simple proxy server in node.js that supports SSL. Maybe that can help you debug your solution. You can find the code and short instructions for generating a self-signed certificate on my Github project: https://github.com/alienhard/malinger.